# Use parted into a Chef recipe to build a partition

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, chef-recipe

Just starting on chef, I'm trying to convert my old bash provisioning scripts to something more modern and realiable, using Chef.

The first script is somewhat i used to build a partition and mount it to /opt.

This is the script: https://github.com/theclue/db2-vagrant/blob/master/provision_for_mount_disk.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
yum install -y parted

parted /dev/sdb mklabel msdos

parted /dev/sdb mkpart primary ext4 0% 100%
sleep 3

#-m swith tells mkfs to only reserve 1% of the blocks for the super block
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1

e2label /dev/sdb1 "opt"

######### mount sdb1 to /opt ##############
chmod 777 /opt

mount /dev/sdb1 /opt
chmod 777 /opt

echo '/dev/sdb1 /opt ext4 defaults 0 0' >> /etc/fstab
```

I found a parted recipe [here](https://github.com/retr0h/cookbook-parted), but it doesn't seem to support all the parameters I need (0% and 100%, to name two) and anyway I've no idea on how to do the formatting/mounting block.

any idea?

Comment: Hi @Gabriele. I think this is the place where you should pull up your sleeves and start digging in. As you could notice, recipe you referenced is executing shell commands under the hood (just like you would). If you're using parted frequently in your scripts take that cookbook and modify it so it soothes your needs. Otherwise, just put the execute block with that "parted" command into your cookbook. It's normal thing to do in Chef ;)

Comment: did it this way :) perhaps not totally elegant...but it works ;)